# How to select the most recent rows from tables

Tags: mysql, select, sql-order-by

I've got table1

```
table1
id          int
myvalue     text
datevalue   datetime ('2016-02-23 19:25:02')
```

And table2

```
table2
id          int
myvalue     text
datevalue   datetime ('2016-02-23 19:27:58')
```

and I want to select the 5 most recent rows for table1 and table2

I guess it's an ORDER BY datevalue DESC LIMIT 5 ...

but I tried many ways without success !

thank you :)

Comment: You've said "I tried many ways without success !" but have not posted even a single one. Anyway, seems you've got 2-3 answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select from both the tables. then,

**Query**

```
select * from 
(
    select * from table1
    union all 
    select * from table2
)t
order by t.datevalue desc limit 5;
```

Comment: thank you , clause where doesn't work, good syntax was :  " select * from ( select * from table1   union all   select * from table2 )t ORDER BY t.datevalue desc limit 5

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It happened in the hurry. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For both tables together :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Table2)
ORDER BY datevalue desc LIMIT 5
```

and for each table seperatly :

```
  SELECT * FROM Table1
   ORDER BY datevalue desc LIMIT 5
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM Table2
   ORDER BY datevalue desc LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use union to get the whole row set (for the two tables), check the correct syntax (MySQL and Oracle for example have different ways of 'calling stuff') and if all else fails to a to_char and order it afterwards (so that you compare strings and no longer dates, which can be tricky sometimes)